# My Wordpress plugin does not create page when I upload a file to media library

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Hey I wrote a custom plugin for my wordpress site which should create a new page with a download link when I upload a file to media library, but it does not seem to work and I am fairly new to php and wordpress ecosystem so I do not know where the problem lies.

Here is the code that I wrote

```
<?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Automatic Download Page Creator
     * Plugin URI: https://example.com/automatic-download-page-creator
     * Description: Automatically creates a page or post with a download link for a file when it is uploaded to the media library.
     * Version: 1.0
     * Author: Wisecraft
     * Author URI: https://example.com
     * License: GPL2
     */

    // Hook into the 'wp_insert_attachment' action
    add_action( 'wp_insert_attachment', 'create_download_page', 10, 2 );

    // Custom function to create the download page or post
    function create_download_page( $attachment_id, $attachment ) {
        // Get the file URL and post title
        $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
        $post_title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );

        // Create the post content with a download link
        $post_content = '<p>Click the link below to download the file:</p>';
        $post_content = '<p><a href="' . $file_url . '">Download ' . $post_title . '</a></p>';

        // Insert the page or post
        $new_post = array(
          'post_type' => 'post', // or 'post'
          'post_title' => $post_title,
          'post_content' => $post_content,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
    }
?>
```

I expected my plugin to create a new page with a custom content when I upload a file to Media Library in WordPress, but it does not do anything and I cannot find a problem with the code as well.

Comment: I don't think `wp_insert_attachment` is an action hook. Even if it was, at what point of execution would it fire? Try registering the function to a plugin activation hook and you've passed arguments to `create_download_page` as though `wp_insert_attachment ` will pass the parameters to it, which it won't. Query through the uploaded images, get the parameters and then call your function.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. You used wrong hook. And if you want add string to existing you need to use .= operator for $post_content. And if you want add Page not Post you need to change post_type in $args array to "page"

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'create_download_page', 10, 1 );
function create_download_page( $attachment_id ) {
   // Get the file URL and post title
   $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
   $post_title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );

   // Create the post content with a download link
   $post_content = '<p>Click the link below to download the file:</p>';
   $post_content .= '<p><a href="' . $file_url . '">Download ' . $post_title . '</a></p>';

   // Insert the page or post
   $new_post = array(
     'post_type' => 'page', // or 'post'
     'post_title' => $post_title,
     'post_content' => $post_content,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
   );
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
}
```